# Filtering realm objects with Swift 3 using Function

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

I am currently upgrading my app from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and trying to figure out how predicates work with Realm now.

I have this simple code:

```
let exercises = category.sections[indexPath.section].exercises.filter { (exercise) in
    self.isVisible(exercise)
}

let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]
```

Where isVisible function is:

```
func isVisible(_ exercise: RepositoryExercise) -> Bool {
    let firstSet = exercise.sets[0]

    if (exercise.sets.count > 1) {
        return true
    } else {
        if (firstSet.seconds > 0 || firstSet.reps > 0) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return exercise.visible
}
```

Where my problem starts is the usage of LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection.

[image]

What's the preferred method of filtering collections in Swift 3 now? I was thinking about using NSPredicate but rewriting this function to use it might be quite hard/look complicated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `category.sections[indexPath.section].exercises` that you are trying to filter?

Comment: List<RepositoryExercise> which is a realm object. Answered below with my `solution`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this topic shortly after https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1046

Wrapped my list in an `Array()` in order to filter on it.

[image]